# onActivityResult not called if Activity went into PictureInPicture mode

Tags: android, onactivityresult, back-stack, picture-in-picture, task-management

## Activities

- Activity `A`: content list
- Activity `B`: player

## Flow

Activity `A` ==> Activity `B`

1. Activity `A` launches Activity `B` using `startActivityForResult`
2. Activity `B` might go into Picture-in-Picture mode
3. Activity `B` calls `setResult` and then `finish`
4. `onActivityResult` from Activity `A` is called

## Issue

When Activity `B` goes into Picture-in-Picture, `onActivityResult` isn't called.

I know that Activity `B` detaches from Activity `A`'s task stack when it goes into Picture-in-Picture, but I would expect the `startActivityForResult` to behave as expected. Is this a bug or is it expected ?

Any workaround would be appreciated. Also, my last resort is to re-do it all and use internal broadcasting to communicate both Activities. Feel free to comment on that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: it is strange, could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as I understand Activity in PIP mode is considered Pause. 
But there is some development in the multi-resume feature. 
To opt-in to this behavior in Android P, add the following meta-data in your app manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.allow_multiple_resumed_activities" android:value="true" />
```

You can read about this [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/get-your-app-ready-for-foldable-phones.html).

Comment: Indeed, the Activity stays in a `paused` state, which might be blocking the call to `onActivityResult`. However, I need a solution for regular devices, not folded ones and also for pre Android P. Thanks tho, +1!

Comment: As you said, for now, the best way would be to use broadcast until the Google team handles this. :-)